# Unicode string replace is not working with a full diacritics Arabic text

Tags: javascript, string, replace, arabic

I want to replace following Arabic text with empty string, but when I do it with `string.replace` function, it does not replace it.

following is the string

> بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ

from http://api.globalquran.com/ayah/2:1/quran-uthmani

code

```
singleAyah.verse.replace('بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ', '');
```

I have even tried unicode

```
singleAyah.verse.replace('\u0628\u0650\u0633\u0652\u0645\u0650 \u0671\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u0650 \u0671\u0644\u0631\u0651\u064e\u062d\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0670\u0646\u0650 \u0671\u0644\u0631\u0651\u064e\u062d\u0650\u064a\u0645\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0653\u0645\u0653', '');
```

still it returns back text.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with arabic, but it looks like the text you are trying to replace (in your call to `String.prototype.replace`) is not the same as the source text. [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dr1sjnn/1/)

Comment: @BrianGradin you are right, but I'm copying and pasting the text. How can I copy exact text from the json string?  I have event tried doing this to get the exact version `console.log("singleAyah.verse = singleAyah.verse.replace('"+singleAyah.verse+"', '')");`  this still didnt work

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly are you trying to do? Your question statement is about replacing text, but your comment above talks about assigning from one location to another...

Comment: it is replacing only.  I'm using that json api link to get the data and then replace it with empty string.  when I get the json api text and use above code or even your code, it does not replace it. I'm guessing the text changes when it comes.. I'm not sure..

Comment: I created [a new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rh0s1tn/) which actually loads from the API. Replacement seems to work to me...

Comment: Yes, that way it works, but I need to use that text as static search text... because on api there are other words like "الٓمٓ" or some other,  http://api.globalquran.com/ayah/4:1/quran-uthmani   if you see, this text is only on start and rest is something else so I want to hide the start one without calling the first api call to get the whole word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visually, your 2 strings are similar, but they have a different unicode string: the order between Fatha **ـَ**  and Shada **ـّ** are exchanged in position. This has no effect on visual since both cases to be rendered the same way with Shadda under Fatha: **ـَّ** **ـَّ**.

> \u0628\u0650\u0633\u0652\u0645\u0650
>   \u0671\u0644\u0644 **\u0651\u064e** \u0647\u0650
>   \u0671\u0644\u0631 **\u0651\u064e**\u062d\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0670\u0646\u0650
>   \u0671\u0644\u0631 **\u0651\u064e**\u062d\u0650\u064a\u0645\u0650
>
> \u0628\u0650\u0633\u0652\u0645\u0650
>   \u0671\u0644\u0644 **\u064e\u0651**\u0647\u0650
>   \u0671\u0644\u0631 **\u064e\u0651**\u062d\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0670\u0646\u0650
>   \u0671\u0644\u0631 **\u064e\u0651**\u062d\u0650\u064a\u0645\u0650

Comment: like this: `verse.replace('بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ', 'REPLACED');`